# Elfinder Yii Cannot modify header information

Tags: yii, nginx, elfinder

I use Yii+ TinyMCE + elfinder.
On my local machine (windows+xampp) all work fine. But after transfer on hosting (nginx) i have problem. When you call elfinder plugin i had error: 
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/h64989/data/www/demo1.webcontora.ru/protected/config/main.php:1) (/home/h64989/data/www/demo1.webcontora.ru/protected/extensions/elfinder/php/elFinder.class.php:362)

I understand that there is a record on the page before header, but why on local machine all good fine?

How i can fix it?

Comment: I think this is a problem of the nginx.

Comment: Or its a problem with the output_buffering parameter in your php.ini file: http://serverfault.com/questions/413245/php-header-redirect-working-in-nginx-even-output-sent

Comment: Google is my friend...